# Comparing MySQL varchars

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue when I sort desc/asc on a column in a database it sorts it like this.

```
9980
91
883
51
507
460
286
243
23
2131
```

Now I figured this is because I made the colum varchar.  Is anyway to get it to sort correctly without changing to the column to int?

Thanks

Comment: what do you have against changing the col to int?

Comment: business requirements, not mine...

Comment: Even though it's possible (see answers below), sorting a casted column probably performs a lot worse than converting the column to the correct data type and use that for sorting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the items to be sorted as if they were numbers, [cast](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) them to an integer:

```
ORDER BY CAST (field AS SIGNED INTEGER)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you must:

```
ORDER BY CAST(`YOUR_COL` AS SIGNED)
```

for DESC

```
ORDER BY CAST(`YOUR_COL` AS SIGNED) DESC
```